# Moving polygons to points using ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a large number of polygons with matching points. I wish to move each respective polygon to its corresponding point (see attached image). I can't use the 'Move To' tool in the 'Editor', as I have too many polygons and points for this to be viable.

Is there a way to do this with ArcPy?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have some common id to link each polygon to Point. Then you can read each id and point xy coordinates as a Dictionary using da.SearchCursor. Then use the Dictionary with da.UpdateCursor to move polygons:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb'
polys = 'areas'
points = 'areas_FeatureToPoint'
common_id_column = 'idcolumn'

d =  {idval:centroidxy for idval,centroidxy in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, [common_id_column,'SHAPE@XY'])} #Store Point id and centroid coordinates in a dictionary

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polys,[common_id_column,'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in d:
            row[1] = d[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            print "Could not find polygon with point id {0}".format(row[0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A starting point in arcpy could be this script, it overwrites the centroid of the polygon:
https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/shifting-features/

```
import arcpy

def shift_features(in_features, x_shift=None, y_shift=None):
    """
    Shifts features by an x and/or y value. The shift values are in
    the units of the in_features coordinate system.

    Parameters:
    in_features: string
        An existing feature class or feature layer.  If using a
        feature layer with a selection, only the selected features
        will be modified.

    x_shift: float
        The distance the x coordinates will be shifted.

    y_shift: float
        The distance the y coordinates will be shifted.
    """

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + (x_shift or 0),
                               row[0][1] + (y_shift or 0)]])

    return
```

If you have a equal ID field in the points and polygons features you could maybe rewrite the updateRow of the centroid like this:

```
def shiftPoly(inPoints, inFcS, inFcSL):

    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFcS, inFcSL)

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (inPoints, ['SHAPE@XY', 'ID']) as sCurs:
        for row in sCurs:
            print("{0}: {1}, {2}".format(row[1], row[0][0], row[0][1]))

            myX = row[0][0]
            myY = row[0][1]

            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inFcSL, "NEW_SELECTION", 
                                        "ID = {}".format(row[1]))

            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFcSL, ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    cursor.updateRow([[myX, myY]])

    return
```