# Placing a predefined polygon at a specific lat+long

Tags: arcpy, polygon

Been a while since I played with arcpy. I have a couple of hundred shapes to add to a FeatureClass.

I'm trying to find a way to "predefine" a polygon, like a square of 10m by 20m, and then "paste" that shape at the hundreds of lat/long co-ordinates I have.

It seems that I have to start from the specified lat/long, and calculate and draw the shape around that point.

Is there not a way to "paste" a shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ArcGIS Desktop Advanced license, instead of arcpy, I would rather use a simpler approach, for example,

1. Place buffers around the points for square features or use Table To Ellipse tool to create rectangular features, and then
2. Create envelopes by using Minimum Bounding Geometry tool.

Comment: I literally have a single point. So the "feature" is a dot. Since I don't have a shape to work with, maybe I must just draw a new (circle) shape centred on that point.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your predefined polygons to be copied or moved to your lat+long coordinates, you would need to have some sort of ID that is linking your coordinates/points with the polygons.

If you have that, I think this previous question provides a very useful ArcPy script to do what you asked:

[How to move polygons to points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352076/how-to-move-polygons-to-points)

Comment: OK, but how do I predefine the polygon?

Comment: From your question I gathered that you already had the shapes, but they just had to be moved according to the coordinate point. Do your shapes already have an existing relation (non-spatial) with the lat+long coordinates? If you want to create a rectangle/square/circle around all of your points, I think @fatih_dur's answer is more efficient